# libGDX: Orthogonal TiledMapRenderer renders just one tile

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm using the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer in libGDX 0.9.9 to render a tiled map in tmx format.

```
maprend = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(board.getTiledMap(), sprtbatch);
```

This renderer renders just one single tile in the bottom left corner.

```
render() {  //(shortened)
sprtbatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
maprend.render(); }
```

Using an IsometricTiledMapRenderer with the same constructor renders the whole map.
Is there a known bug in the orthogonal renderer or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `maprend.setView(camera);` before calling `maprend.render();`.

Note: There is no need to set the projection matrix of the spritebach there.